# How to find a minimum value in given list using recursion function

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried to write a recursion function to find minimum value in my list but I stuck on what to do next.

```
def findRecMin(aList):
if(len(aList)==1):
    return aList[0]
else:
    min_of_the_rest = findRecMin(aList[1:])

myList = [16, 20, 3, 37, 95, 49, 61]
n = findRecMin(myList)
print(n)
```

I need to find a minimum value of the given list. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: in your function you dont return the minimum value from the function

Comment: what do i need to add to the function to make it return minimum value?

Comment: well you need to test each element and track the minimum element as you recursivly call your function. Then return when you have the minimum value.

Answer (score 0):

Writing recursive functions like this is straightforward if you take a "leap of faith" and assume that the recursive call gives a correct result. In this case, your code

```py
min_of_the_rest = findRecMin(aList[1:])
```

makes a recursive call on the tail of the list, which is everything except the first element. So let's assume it truly does give you the minimum element from the tail; the only problem you need to solve now is, **how do I use the first element at `aList[0]`, and the minimum value of the tail, to find the minimum of the whole list?** The answer is that whichever is smaller, either `aList[0]` or `min_of_the_rest`, is the true minimum of the whole list. So we can write something like

```py
if aList[0] < min_of_the_rest:
    return aList[0]
else:
    return min_of_the_rest
```

Or more simply, using the `min` function,

```py
return min(aList[0], min_of_the_rest)
```

---

This approach works for writing many kinds of recursive function on lists; assume the recursive call gives you the correct result for the tail, then work out how to combine the first element with that result in order to get the result for the whole list. For example:

- Finding the sum: the sum of the whole list is `aList[0] + sum_of_the_rest`.
- Finding the length: the length of the whole list is `1 + len_of_the_rest`.
- Testing whether the number `x` is in the list: `aList[0] == x or the_rest_contains_x`.